# Makefile:107: recipe for target '_shtns.so' failed

Tags: python, c, gcc

I am having a problem while trying to compile the [shtns](https://users.isterre.fr/nschaeff//SHTns/index.html) library with python support. I do:

```
./configure --prefix=$HOME/local --enable-python
make
```

and I get:

```
(...)
building '_shtns' extension
gcc -march=native -DNDEBUG -g -fwrapv -O2 -Wall -Wstrict-prototypes -fno-strict-aliasing -Wdate-time -D_FORTIFY_SOURCE=2 -g -fdebug-prefix-map=/build/python2.7-lMBuS3/python2.7-2.7.12=. -fstack-protector-strong -Wformat -Werror=format-security -fPIC -I/home/david/.local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/numpy/core/include -I/usr/include/python2.7 -c shtns_numpy_wrap.c -o build/temp.linux-x86_64-2.7/shtns_numpy_wrap.o -fopenmp
x86_64-linux-gnu-gcc -pthread -shared -Wl,-O1 -Wl,-Bsymbolic-functions -Wl,-Bsymbolic-functions -Wl,-z,relro -fno-strict-aliasing -DNDEBUG -g -fwrapv -O2 -Wall -Wstrict-prototypes -Wdate-time -D_FORTIFY_SOURCE=2 -g -fdebug-prefix-map=/build/python2.7-lMBuS3/python2.7-2.7.12=. -fstack-protector-strong -Wformat -Werror=format-security -L/home/david/local/lib -Wdate-time -D_FORTIFY_SOURCE=2 -g -fdebug-prefix-map=/build/python2.7-lMBuS3/python2.7-2.7.12=. -fstack-protector-strong -Wformat -Werror=format-security build/temp.linux-x86_64-2.7/shtns_numpy_wrap.o sht_init.o sht_fly.o sht_omp.o -L/home/david/local/lib -lfftw3_omp -lfftw3 -lm -o build/lib.linux-x86_64-2.7/_shtns.so -L/home/david/local/lib
/usr/bin/ld: /home/david/local/lib/libfftw3.a(assert.o): relocation R_X86_64_PC32 against symbol `stdout@@GLIBC_2.2.5' can not be used when making a shared object; recompile with -fPIC
/usr/bin/ld: final link failed: Bad value
collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
error: command 'x86_64-linux-gnu-gcc' failed with exit status 1
Makefile:107: recipe for target '_shtns.so' failed
make: *** [_shtns.so] Error 1
```

I think those are the relevant lines. It suggests to compile using the -fpic flag, but that is already in my CFLAGS environment variable, as you can see in the first gcc line. The problem is with the 'x86_64-linux-gnu-gcc' bit. Any suggestions?

Comment: I have installed this library in other computers and it all worked smoothly...

Thanks in advance!

Comment: All right, I solved it. I realized what I had to recompile with the -fPIC flag is the fftw library.

Maybe this helps someone.